# MySQL multiple join with if

Tags: mysql

MySQL noob here.

So I have a main table like this TableA (ID int, TableBID int, TableCID int), I want left join TableA with TableB (ID int, Value1 int, AgeID int) and TableC (ID int, Value1 int, AgeID int) in order to get the AgeID.

For table A, it will only have value for either TableBID or TableCID. The other one will be 0.

And finally, I want to use the AgeID I got from TableB or TableC and left join Age (ID int, age int) to get the age.

I expect the table I get ar the end is in this format (TableA.ID, Age.age)

For now the query I have is

```
SELECT a.ID, age.age
FROM TableA AS a
LEFT JOIN TableB AS b ON a.TableBID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN TableC AS c ON a.TableCID = c.ID
```

Then I am stuck.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery to make the origin of the `AgeID` transparent:

```
select sub.ID, Age.age
from (
    select a.ID as ID, if(a.TableBID, b.AgeID, c.AgeID) as AgeID
    from TableA a
    left join TableB b on a.TableBID = b.ID
    left join TableC c on a.TableCID = c.ID
) sub
join Age on sub.AgeID = Age.ID
```

An alternative would be joining directly with an `OR` clause:

```
select a.ID as ID, Age.age
from TableA a
left join TableB b on a.TableBID = b.ID
left join TableC c on a.TableCID = c.ID
join Age on (
    Age.ID = b.AgeID
    or
    Age.ID = c.AgeID
)
```

Comment: I like the one with OR clause and I assume this is the one run faster than others since it has less join.

Comment: It's worth checking the [EXPLAIN plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) if speed is important in your application, because the one with less JOINs may not necessarily be the fastest. JOINs can be very quick with the right indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can LEFT JOIN with Age from both TableB and TableC, and then use a [COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp) to get the age value from whichever JOIN was successful. Here's an example of how you would do it with your existing query:

```
SELECT a.ID, COALESCE(bAge.age, cAge.age) AS age
FROM TableA AS a
LEFT JOIN TableB AS b ON a.TableBID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN TableC AS c ON a.TableCID = c.ID
LEFT JOIN Age AS bAge ON b.AgeID = bAge.ID
LEFT JOIN Age AS cAge ON c.AgeID = cAge.ID
```